# Использование xml запросов в yandex.tank

Tags: яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

Можно ли с помощью яндекс.танка провести нагрузочной тестирование для веб-сервиса, посылая xml запросы? Не могу найти упоминания этого в документации и интернете.

Comment: Возможно есть другие более удобные способы для нагрузочного тестирования веб сервиса? спам xml запрсов

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о xml over http, и нет необходимости валидировать приходящие ответы, то вполне подойдет yandex-tank/phantom.
Подготовка запросов ничем не отличается от [обычной подготовки POST запросов](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#preparing-requests)

Если же нужно разбирать приходящие ответы, то лучше использовать jmeter, с [xpath assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion)